# Parsing UnicodeSyntax with haskell-src-exts

Tags: haskell, haskell-src-exts

I have a Haskell source file which using Unicode syntax:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}
succ' :: Int → Int
succ' = succ

main :: IO ()
main = print $ succ' 1
```

This parses and runs fine with GHC. Additionally, stylish-haskell and hlint (both based on haskell-src-exts) can read this file without any trouble. However, when I try to parse it myself using haskell-src-exts:

```
import Language.Haskell.Exts (parseModule)

main = do
    x <- readFile "test.hs"
    print $ parseModule x
```

I get the error message:

```
ParseFailed (SrcLoc {srcFilename = "<unknown>.hs", srcLine = 6, srcColumn = 1}) "TypeOperators is not enabled"
```

However, providing UnicodeSyntax explicitly in the extensions list or using parseFile works just fine:

```
import Language.Haskell.Exts

main = do
    x <- readFile "test.hs"
    print $ parseModuleWithMode defaultParseMode
        { extensions = [UnicodeSyntax]
        } x

    parseFile "test.hs" >>= print
```

Any idea why the first approach fails?

Comment: From a cursory glance at the source, it doesn't look like `parseModule` extracts language pragmas from the source _before_ parsing (`parseFile` does do that by calling `getExtensions`). By the time parsing has begun, it is already too late to enable unicode syntax.

Comment: You're right, thanks! It looks like parseFileContents is the appropriate function for my use case. If you convert your comment into an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Done! I wasn't absolutely sure this was the reason, but on more thinking, it definitely seems to be the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a cursory glance at the source, it doesn't look like `parseModule` extracts language pragmas from the source before parsing (`parseFile` does do that by calling `getExtensions`). By the time parsing has begun, it is already too late to enable unicode syntax.