# Haskell-src-exts throws TemplateHaskell error

Tags: parsing, haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, template-haskell

I'm trying to use the [haskell-src-exts](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) package to parse Haskell modules. Currently, I'm trying to parse the [acme-io](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-io) package's module, but I keep getting this error no matter what parse mode I try:

```
*** Exception: fromParseResult: Parse failed at [System/IO/Unsafe/Really/IMeanIt] (1:57): TemplateHaskell is not enabled
```

The module mentioned makes no references to TemplateHaskell, not in it's `LANGUAGE` pragma, nor is there a `$` anywhere in the source file.

I'm wondering if my parse mode has something to do with it - here it is:

```
defaultParseMode { parseFilename = toFilePath m
                 , baseLanguage = Haskell2010
                 , extensions = []
                 , ignoreLanguagePragmas = True
                 , ignoreLinePragmas = True
                 , fixities = Nothing
                 }
```

I've also tried to replace the `extensions` field with `knownExtensions` from [the parsing suite](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Extension.html#v:knownExtensions), without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate question of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784076/parsing-unicodesyntax-with-haskell-src-exts) - using the `parseFile` function fixed the issue. However, the reader should note that `haskell-src-exts` uses different parsing than GHC - I ran into another similar issue right after this, because [haskell-src-exts can't handle multi-param contexts without -XMultiParamTypeClasses, yet GHC can](https://github.com/haskell-suite/haskell-src-exts/issues/29), borking the parser if you're scraping Hackage. [Hint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) may be a better option, can't say for sure though.