# parseModule does not recognize some language extensions as enabled

Tags: haskell, haskell-src-exts

How do I make `parseModule` parse Haskell files with language extensions?

Using `parseModule` from `Language.Haskell.Exts`, when I try to parse the file `Core.hs` from https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Core.hs  I get the error:

```
XGene-exe: fromParseResult: Parse failed at [<unknown>.hs] (248:25): Illegal data/newtype declaration
```

This appears to be because it is using an existential type:

```
data Layout a = forall l. (LayoutClass l a, Read (l a)) => Layout (l a)
```

yet `Core.hs` has the `ExistentialQuantification` language extension pragma at the top:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, FlexibleInstances, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving,
             MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeSynonymInstances, DeriveDataTypeable #-}
```

when I try it for `Layout.hs` (https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Core.hs) I get the error
`Parse failed at [<unknown>.hs] (53:1): MultiParamTypeClasses language extension is not enabled. Please add {-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-} pragma at the top of your module.` despite there pragma being there:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, PatternGuards, TypeSynonymInstances, DeriveDataTypeable #-}
```

`Main.hs` and `Operations.hs` gives the error `Malformed context: FlexibleContexts is not enabled` despite having `{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleContexts #-}`

`Config.hs`, `ManageHook.hs` and `Stackset.hs` parse correctly.

xmonad builds when I do a cabal build.

Comment: Wild guess: [*Parsing UnicodeSyntax with haskell-src-exts*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15784076/2751851) might be relevant. It sounds plausible that the extensions that are causing trouble here should be handled in the way `UnicodeSyntax` is over there, though I haven't looked closely enough at it to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Guidance of duplode's comment, the issue was that I was using `parseModule`, instead of `parseFile`.

`parseFile` automatically picks up the language extensions, whereas if I wanted to parse just the source code then I would have to use `parseModuleWithMode` and add the relevant extensions.

`parseFile` fits my use case better.